# pydev: what is the rationale behind having several source folders?

Tags: python, eclipse, module, package, pydev

I am using Eclipse + pydev and have no existing source folders, but have nested modules such as root.nested described in http://pydev.org/manual_101_first_module.html. Would it make any sence to have several several folders given that each package creates its own subfolder (and packages have to reside in a source folder). In other words: why would it make sense to have packages in different source folders?

Thanks!

Comment: By 'source folders', do you mean PyDev projects?

Comment: Nope; source folder is one level lower. Right click on Pydev Project, it will offer you to create a source folder. There can be several source folders in each project, hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs below, it sounds like 'source folder' is just a special designation within PyDev that causes PyDev to automatically add that folder to the PYTHONPATH for the project.  I guess it's more of a personal preference as to how you want to organize your project.

http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html